# DataTable Row Background Color

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a `<h:datatable>` like the following:

```
<h:dataTable styleClass="myDataTable" id="dataTable1" value="#{myBean.listColors}"
binding="#{myBean.dataTableColor}"/>
```

I also have two `<h:commandlink>` which I use to navigate through the rows of my DataTable. Those buttons take the data from a List and input them into their respective fields (`<h:inputText>`). I need to select the current row, highlighting it with a different background color, when the user click on the Previous/Next button.

I would like to do that on my bean class, but it's OK if you provide any solution in JavaScript or JSF (I'm kind of new to this technologies). Sorry for any technical mistakes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you can use primefaces library. it provides many nice solutions on dataTables. check out this [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml)

If u have a datatable u can set attributes such as selection which indicates the selected item :

```
<p:dataTable id="dtId" var="items" value="#{urBean.items}" selection="#{urBean.selectedItem}" rowKey="#{item.id}">
```

meanwhile on ur commandLink you can call the managed bean's method to change the selection object to previous and next.

Comment: I'm using an didactical example, but I can't use PrimeFaces. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) DateTable component, I think it will give you more powerful options.

Comment: I'm using an didactical example, but I can't use PrimeFaces. :(